# How to call one module to another module in yii2

Tags: inheritance, module, yii2

I have two modules `user` and `studio` But both module having same `inquiries` form. So I don't want to re-write code in `studio` module.
I already done my `inquiries` form with email functionality in the `user` module. So I just want to call all the `user` module `inquiries` model, controller and view in my `studio` module.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

If you have already developed the inquiry form in `user` module, you can develop the inquiry form **view** in the `studio` module.

Then, change the form action to use the `user` module inquiry form URL in `studio`.